# How do I fix NbClust Error solve.default(W) in mtcars dataset?

Tags: r

I used NbClust with the example data mtcars in R and found error.
How to fix this?

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars.scale=scale(mtcars)

library(NbClust)
nc = NbClust(mtcars.scale, min.nc = 2,max.nc = 5, method = "kmeans")
```

Error in solve.default(W) :

> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number =
>   6.94466e-17

In addition: Warning message:

```
In log(det(P)/det(W)) : `NaNs produced`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix colinearity on your data (mtcars).

The error means your design matrix is not invertible and therefore can't be used to develop a regression model. This results from linearly dependent columns, i.e. strongly correlated variable.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm